# Why does "ls -l" display the year of my (jar) file as "16:18"?

Tags: terminal

I was looking through my file system and noticed that the date of `mysql-v5.jar` is formatted incorrectly.

```
~/Dev/Lib$ ls -l  
total 29128  
-rw-r-----@ 1 johndoe  staff   2256213 Mar 16  2015 guava-18.0.jar  
-rw-r--r--@ 1 johndoe  staff  11684781 Jan 30  2012 kuromoji-0.7.7.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 johndoe  staff    968670 May  4 16:18 mysql-v5.jar
```

What is going on?

(So far, all 3 `jar` files have worked just fine for me. I can't remember where I downloaded those files from.)

Comment: @Tetsujin the reason I did the tag I did was to make the `16:18` bold (which is impossible with standard markdown). However, if you are going to use the four space indent, one should put `<!-- language: lang-none -->` in front of it to disable the syntax highlighting that is distracting when it isn't a programming language.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the bold - doesn't stand out much & have no idea how to get the no lang tag to work, so I just rolled it back. Usually the pre tag just messes up SE markdown so I binned it without even really thinking about it. Rolled back, looks fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin the bold is a subtle look in `<pre>`, and it does take some care to get it just right (especially if you *do* want code formatting in there - [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88138/22048)). Its doable, though it often takes a try or two to get it just right without messing up the rest of the formatting (insert rant about [grey lines with just white space above and below the preformat block...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/301231/revisions)). Always, thank you for the revert back.

Comment: Worth mentioning there are a couple of date parameters to `ls` that make this less ambiguous. Try `ls -T` on OS X.

Comment: @miken32 For me, in an OS X bash shell,  `ls -lT` gives the consistent date format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From `man ls` (The Long Format):

> If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or future, then the year of the last modification is displayed in place of the hour and minute fields.

Or in other words: It works as designed.

Comment: I especially like the "6 months in the ... future" part :-)

Comment: 3 days and 5 hours from now, I would not have been able to notice that about the long format!

Comment: confirmed. This afternoon, the year, instead of the time of `mysql-v5.jar`, began to be displayed.